# MikTeX error with fltpoint.tex after installation of MinionPro

Tags: windows, minionpro, miktex2.9

I went through the `FontPro` install process and it seemed to have been successful. But now running the following in MiKTeX gives an error

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document} 
  Hello World.
\end{document}
```

as follows:

```
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) 
(./MinionPro.sty (./MinionPro-FontDef.sty (./otfontdef.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/fltpoint/fltpoint.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/fltpoint/fltpoint.tex))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Mn@scale 

l.99 \Mn@calc@bsize{\Mn@s@capt}{8.5}
```

The MiKTeX Package Manager lists the existing minion2newtx package and the mnsymbol font but nothing from the install process! OTOH, fc-list shows, as expected, the four Adobe Reader files
    MinionPro-Regular.pfb: Minion Pro:style=Regular
    MinionPro-It.pfb: Minion Pro:style=Italic
    MinionPro-BoldIt.pfb: Minion Pro:style=Bold Italic
    MinionPro-Bold.pfb: Minion Pro:style=Bold

and the same files in my `$TEXMFLOCAL` directory.

Has there been an error in the Windows 10 install process and, if so how to fix it?

Comment: Your log shows texlive files. So why MiKTeX In the question?

Comment: The actual error came from LuaLaTex (same for pdfLaTeX).  Perhaps wrongly, I thought that MiKTeX, which is what I usually use, would see the installed font.

Comment: Don't confuse tex engines and tex systems. Beside this: something is wrong in your local MinionPro.sty. fltpoint.tex and sty is already closed when you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ulrike pointed out, there was a problem with the MinionPro.sty file which didn't relate to fltpoint.tex.  I've fixed that and will post a related question re finding the correct file version.